# Изменить абсолютный путь до файла

Tags: php

Есть сайт примерно со следующим способом размещения файлов

```
+---index.php
\---Web
|   +---index.php
|   \---p
|   |   +--index.php
|   |   \---folder
|   |   |   +---index.php
|   |   |   +---img.jpg
```

Все запросы через .htaccess перенаправляются в файл `index.php` находящийся в корне, и там уже идет подключении файла из нужной директории. Например, при обращении к файлу `web/p/folder/index.php` в браузере url выглядит так `site.ru/p/folder/index.php` т.е. из url'a убирается имя папки `web`. Проблема заключается в том, что в файле `web/p/folder/index.php` подключается картинка `<img src="/img.jpg">` абсолютный путь до картинки выглядит так `site.ru/p/folder/img.jpg`, т.е. из пути убирается имя папки web. Нужно сделать чтобы при задании относительного пути до картинки абсолютный путь указывал на истинное расположение файла с картинкой т.е. `site.ru/web/p/folder/img.jpg`.

Возможно ли как-то реализовать может через .htaccess как-то перенаправлять?
Решения типа такого `<img src="/../../img.jpg">` не подходит.

Comment: Пффф. А почему бы, раз картинка лежит в том же каталоге что и скрипт, указать адрес так `<img src="img.jpg">` ? И вообще вы глупость несёте. У вас же `.htaccess` перенаправляет всё в корень сайта. Вы не можете зайти по адресу `site.ru/p/folder/index.php`

Comment: @ArchDemon там написано `там уже идет подключении файла из нужной директории`. `<img src="img.jpg">` так не работает, путь до картинки выглядит так `site.ru/p/folder/img.jpg` а нужно `site.ru/web/p/folder/img.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Извиняюсь за излишнюю прямоту, но скажу как есть, чтобы дошло.

Сначала придумают кривую архитектуру, а потом мучаются с ней, героически решают возникающие проблемы. У вас [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) в чистом виде: "доктор, когда я <вот так делаю> у меня что-то хрустит -- А вы <вот так> не делайте".

Что вам мешает сложить все картинки в папку /img/ (а загружаемые пользователями - в /upload/) и забыть про проблему, вынесенную в вопрос?

Все ссылки на картинки будут идти как `<img src="/img/subfolder/something.jpg"` и проблем не будет.

Пока что по получается, что ваши инструменты диктуют вам погрязнуть в проблемах, а вы будете идти у них на поводу. Это неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

Следует все картинки положить в корень сайта и в коде поменять полные пути к ним.

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит

Comment: @t16bz а почему бы не заменить пути картинок в файле web/p/folder/index.php

Comment: Потому что на сайт часто загружаются новые файлы, и менять постоянно пути до картинок не очень удобно.